# Leetcode210. Why my code is wrong in a particular case?

Tags: c++

Here is the Question(https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-ii/description/). 
And my solution is from the "Introduction to Algorithms".
Use the DFS algorithm. And color the node with white, grey, and black.

1. mark all the nodes white.
2. when a node is discovered, mark grey.
3. when a node is finished, mark black.
4. when an edge is backward, which means has a grey adjacent node. It has a circle, it should null.

But I pass most of the cases. But some of them are not.
Could Anyone help me out?

The Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    enum {WHITE, GRAY, BLACK};

    vector<vector<int>> graph;
    vector<int> colors;
    list<int> topo;

    void add_edge(vector<vector<int>>& graph, pair<int, int>& p) {
        graph[p.second].push_back(p.first);
    }
    bool visit(vector<vector<int>>& graph, int i) {
        if (colors[i] == WHITE) {
            colors[i] = GRAY;
            bool ret = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].size(); j++) {
                if (colors[graph[i][j]] == WHITE)
                    ret = ret && visit(graph, graph[i][j]);
                else if (colors[graph[i][j]] == GRAY)
                    ret =  false;
                else
                    ret =  false;

            }

            colors[i] = BLACK;
            topo.push_front(i);
            return ret;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool dfs(vector<vector<int>>& graph) {
        for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
            if (!visit(graph, i))
                return false;
        return true;
    }



public:
    vector<int> findOrder(int numCourses, vector<pair<int, int>>& prerequisites) {
        graph.resize(numCourses, {});
        colors.resize(numCourses, WHITE);

        for (auto& pre: prerequisites)
            add_edge(graph, pre);

        if (!dfs(graph))
            return {};

        vector<int> ret (topo.begin(),topo.end());
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in

```
        for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].size(); j++) {
            if (colors[graph[i][j]] == WHITE)
                ret = ret && visit(graph, graph[i][j]);
            else if (colors[graph[i][j]] == GRAY)
                ret =  false;
            else
                ret =  false;
        }
```

The last else is when the node is BLACK, which means it already processed and pushed into the result. So it will not make the graph invalid. Just remove the last else, it will work. Like this:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].size(); j++) {
            if (colors[graph[i][j]] == WHITE)
                ret = ret && visit(graph, graph[i][j]);
            else if (colors[graph[i][j]] == GRAY)
                ret =  false;
            /* else
                ret =  false; */
        }
```